# Discretizing kinematics of moving object

Tags: kinematics, velocity, relative-motion, discrete, distance

I think this is a simple question, but I'm unable to find the relationship:

The relative distance between two objects at any time $t$ can be written as:

$x_r(t)=x_{ro}+\int_{t_0}^{t_f}v_r(t)dt$

where:

$x_r(t)$ :is the relative distance at time $t$.

$x_{r0}$ : is the initial relative distance.

$v_r$: is the relative velocity between the two objects.

Now, I need to see how the relative distance is changing with respect to time and discretize it, I have the final result as:

$x_r(k+1)=x_r(k)+v_r(k)T_s + \frac{1}{2}T_s^2[a_t(k)-a_h(k)]$

where:

$T_s$: is the sampling time.

$a_t$: is the acceleration of the first object.

$a_h$:is the acceleration of the second object.

I know that:

$\dot{x_r}=v_r(t)$, and $\dot{x_r}=\frac{x_r(k+1)-x_r(k)}{T_s}$.

From that, I got:
$x_r(k+1)=x_r(k)+v_r(k)T_s$

But I'm not sure I know how the other terms in the equation are coming?

Comment: $x=\dfrac{a}{2}t^{2}$

Comment: @Eli, I am sorry, could you elaborate more?

Comment: I this that this equation $ \frac{1}{2}T_s^2[a_t(k)-a_h(k)]$ come from my above equation

Comment: Is $v_r(t)$ given? Or the forces and accelerations are given? I suggest using Runge-Kutta 4 th order method.